# Fitting a dishwasher into integrated cabinets

Tags: appliances, dishwasher, fitting

I want to fit a dishwasher into the kitchen of my new house. There is an ideal place for it next to the washing machine, however as the washing machine is integrated, it looks like it's attached to the side of the cabinet - which means I can't remove the cabinet to replace it with the dishwasher, as then neither appliance would have anything to attach to!

Any suggestions? Can you get dishwashers that are narrow enough to fit between the sides of the cabinet (so 55-56cm instead of 58-59 to allow for the thickness of the sides - the current cabinet is 60cm wide)? We're happy to have a freestanding one instead of an integrated one, but still need to support the washing machine somehow...

I'm in the UK if that makes any difference.

Comment: Washing machine? As in laundry? In the kitchen? Dishwashers typically attach only to the underside of the countertop. They're free-standing, more or less.

Comment: Yup - we don't have the luxury of a separate room for laundry. I'm not too worried about the free-standing-ness of the dishwasher, as I don't mind getting a totally free-standing one, but I can't remove the side of the cabinet, as it appears the washing machine is attached to it, so the space is too narrow for a standard dishwasher...

Comment: Typically (in the US, anyway) there are several standard sizes designed for common openings (18" compact, 24" standard). I doubt you'll find a unit with that particular width.

Comment: 60 cm is the european standard for dishwashers (23 5/8"). I have installed many over here in high end homes.

Comment: Not sure on UK's allowances for dishwashers, but two possible options to consider if they are allowed.  One is the countertop dishwasher and the other is the low profile (about 1/2 height built in).  These both are sold in the US for tiny homes, mobile homes or apartments and such.  They both come in multiple widths.  My wife wants one to install under her kitchen sink if I ever get "round2it".